# javascript help me fix my first hands on code

Tags: javascript, html

help me fix this, simple convert to roman numerals code. with two input box, first where i input a number, 2nd box where the result will be shown. and a submit button

result wont show up on 2nd box after hitting convert/submit button

js code:

```js
    function toRoman(){
 var num = document.getElementById('num').value;
 var result = "";
 var db = { 'M':1000, 'CM':900,'D':500,'CD':400, 'C':100, 'XC':90, 'L':50, 'XL':40, 'X':10, 'IX':9, 'V':5, 'IV':4, 'I':1 };
 for(var i in db){
  var m = parseInt(num/db[i]);
  result = i.repeat(m);
  num = num%db[i];
 }
 return result;
 document.getElementById('result').value = result;
    }
```

```html
    
    <body>
    
    <label for="num">Number</label><br/>
    <input type="Number" name="num" id="num"><br/><br/>
    <label for="result">Result</label><br/>
    <textarea id="result" name="result"></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Convert!" onclick="toRoman()">
    
    <script src="toRoman.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem.  What isn't working?  In what way does this fail?  When you debug this using your browser's debugging tools, where does it go wrong?

Comment: You need to be specific on the things or steps or you already did to fix it.

Comment: you should indent your code (industry-standard is usually 4 spaces), but more importantly, as david said, explain your issue

Comment: result wont show up on 2nd input box

Comment: I don't see any code that references your `result` element... why would it populate?

Comment: document.getElementById('result').value = result;

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: @anneb: There are a variety of things wrong with the code here.  But the first thing you really need to do is start using your browser's debugging tools.  Open the debugging console and see if there are any errors.  Place breakpoints in the JavaScript code and observe its runtime behavior and values.  You can actually *observe* what the code is doing, rather than just change random things and hope for the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're overwriting the value of `result` in each iteration of your loop instead of adding to it.**

Change it to `result += i.repeat(m);` instead.

Also, you'll have to either remove your `return` line, move it to the end of the function, or implement the function in a different way - `return` will exit the function at that line, meaning your last line (populating the result box) will never execute.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
function toRoman() {
  var num = +(document.getElementById('num').value);
  var result = "";
  var db = {
    'M': 1000,
    'CM': 900,
    'D': 500,
    'CD': 400,
    'C': 100,
    'XC': 90,
    'L': 50,
    'XL': 40,
    'X': 10,
    'IX': 9,
    'V': 5,
    'IV': 4,
    'I': 1
  };
  for (var i in db) {
    var m = parseInt(num / db[i]);
    result += i.repeat(m);
    num = num % db[i];
  }
  document.getElementById('result').value = result;

}
```

```html
<label for="num">Number</label>
<br/>
<input type="Number" name="num" id="num">
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="result">Result</label>
<br/>
<textarea id="result" name="result"></textarea>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Convert!" onclick="toRoman()">
```

---

**And a piece of advice...**

Try implementing some basic debugging steps when you're looking for issues in your code - throw a few `console.log()` lines in your function so you know it's executing, and you can ensure that your values are returning what you expect.

With a simple `console.log(result)` in your loop, I was able to see that somewhere in the middle, `result` *did* in fact have a value, however by the end of the loop, it *no longer had a value*. This lead me to question "Why would it have a value in the middle but not at the end, unless we're removing the value with each loop?" - and sure enough, there was your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Only after going through the comments I realized what your problem was, which isn't a good practise to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Anyway, your code has no reference to the element with the id 'result'. The last statement that you have will never get fired because it is after the return statement, so it will probably give an error saying 'code unreachable' in the debugger.

Instead of `return result;` you should have something like:

`document.getElementById('result').value = result;`

Or, you can keep your return statement but move this line move above it. So the final structure will be something like

```
document.getElementById('result').value = result;
return result;
```

Comment: Please flesh out your answer a bit more, perhaps providing an example of your fix in action. (*Spoiler alert: It still doesn't work.*)

Comment: Also as a function, it would be better to use return and then call it inside the .value like `document.getElementById('result').value = toRoman()`

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
return result;
document.getElementById('result');
```

to

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
```